# error al mostrar informacion PHP

Tags: php, sql

CODIGO CONEXION

```
<?php 
$cons_usuario="root";
$cons_contra="";
$cons_base_datos="test";
$cons_equipo="localhost";

$con= mysqli_connect($cons_equipo,$cons_usuario,$cons_contra,$cons_base_datos);
if(!$con)
{
    echo "<h3>No se ha podido conectar PHP - MySQL, verifique sus datos.</h3><hr><br>";
}
else
{
   // echo "<h3>Conexion Exitosa PHP - MySQL</h3><hr><br>";
}

 ?>

CODIGO CONSULTA
<?php
require("../../conexion/conexion.php");

$sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT tanque.id as 'id tanque',especie.nombre,cepa.nombre_cepa,
min_max_cepa.id_min_max,min_max_cepa.min,min_max_cepa.max,sonda.id_sonda,sonda.parametro,
nodo_sonda.socket from tanque,solicitud_tanques,cepa,especie,min_max_cepa,sonda,nodo_sonda
where tanque.id =solicitud_tanques.id_tanque
and cepa.id = solicitud_tanques.id_cepas
and cepa.id_especie = especie.id
and min_max_cepa.id_cepa = cepa.id
and min_max_cepa.id_sonda = sonda.id_sonda
and nodo_sonda.id_sonda = sonda.id_sonda
AND tanque.id = '54' GROUP by sonda.id_sonda ORDER by min_max_cepa.id_min_max ASC )t1,
(SELECT tanque.id,tanque.nombre,max(uploadtemp.id_escalon_viaje_ubicacion)
as 'id ultimo registro de los sockets',
uploadtemp.socket_a ,uploadtemp.socket_b ,uploadtemp.socket_c ,uploadtemp.socket_d,uploadtemp.socket_e,
uploadtemp.socket_f FROM tanque,uploadtemp,solicitud_tanques,solicitudes,viajes,estacion,nodo_sonda,sonda
where tanque.id = uploadtemp.id_tanque
and solicitud_tanques.id_solicitud = solicitudes.id
and viajes.id_solicitudes =solicitudes.id
and viajes.id_estacion = estacion.id 
and tanque.id_estacion = estacion.id
and uploadtemp.id_escalon_viaje_ubicacion =(SELECT MAX(uploadtemp.id_escalon_viaje_ubicacion)from uploadtemp)
and tanque.id = '54'
)t2";

 $rs=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $datos=array();
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $datos[]=$row;
 }
 echo json_encode($datos);
?>
```

me muestra este error al cargar la pagina

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\smobil_app\Modulos\Viajes\detalle_tanque.php on line
>   29 []

a que se debe? y debo hacer para mostrar los datos???

Comment: Esto es porque no te has conectado bien a la base de datos, revisa la variable '$con' y la función mysql_connect()

Comment: bien,parece que en la conexion escribi mal el nombe de la base de datos, pero ahora cuando cargo la pagina me muestra "[]"

Answer (score 0):

tienes puesto:

```
 $rs=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

pero para mysqli_query los parametros van al reves:

```
 $rs=mysqli_query($sql, $con);
```

Revisa la doc:

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con mi archivo para conexiones para ver si te resulta mejor,

```html
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db="test";
$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db);

?>
```